# How do Telegram bots that find users channel list work?

Tags: security, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

Recently, I became interested in searching for information in Telegram, and I found several bots that allow you to find a list of groups and channels in which a user is.
I checked and they actually work.
Why does Telegram have such a vulnerability for user privacy?
Is it possible to avoid this?

From what I understand, these bots have a large database of groups and channels, but I also wonder if the bot only works with open groups, or if it also has information from public channels or closed groups.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a below code that will copy messages from a channel that user select and paste it in bot. You can modify to copy message from one channel and create your own channel to paste them. For example Forex Signal

```
from telethon import TelegramClient, sync

api_id = 'your_id_from_my.telegram.org'
api_hash = 'your_id_hash_from_my.telegram.org'

client = TelegramClient('session', api_id, api_hash).start()

# get all the channels that I can access
channels = {d.entity.username: d.entity
            for d in client.get_dialogs()
            if d.is_channel}

# prompt user to select a channel
print("Available Channels:")
for username, entity in channels.items():
    print(f"{username} - {entity.title}")

selected_channel_username = input("Enter the username of the channel you want to view: ")

# check if the selected channel username is valid
if selected_channel_username in channels:
    selected_channel = channels[selected_channel_username]

    # get the latest chat from the selected channel
    latest_message = client.get_messages(selected_channel, limit=1)[0]

    print(f"\nLatest Chat from {selected_channel_username} - {selected_channel.title}:")
    print(f"{latest_message.sender_id}: {latest_message.text}")

else:
    print(f"Invalid channel username: {selected_channel_username}")
```

Comment: Oh, the point is to just search in open groups and large search powers, interesting, thanks!
(I don't think I want to implement it, I was just curious how it works)